# Why my dropdown list is not showing in Select2?

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

Whenever i comment this script, select2 works perfectly but my other function are affected by commenting this code.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

This is my dropdown

```
<select class="roles form-control" name="roles[]" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1">Admin</option>
 <option value="2">Agent</option>
 <option value="3">Customer</option>
 </select>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".roles").select2();
</script>
```

Select2 cdn link

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"> </script>
```

I am new to laravel and applying select2 for the first time. No idea where i went wrong.

Comment: It's because different libraries like jQuery and others are all integrated in this app.js file using Laravel Mix. So don't comment it out.

Comment: When i uncomment app.js, select2 dropdown doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with your javascript code triggers too early. Your code calls `$(".roles").select2();` immediately even before the select element is created.

You should run the code when the page and elements are already created
and ready which is triggered by document ready event.

In jQuery you can just write

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   .... your code here
});
```

or a shorthand

```
$(function() {
   .... your code here
});
```

So your code should look like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".roles").select2();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine while i comment app.js
What to do with this app.js?

Comment: have you run npm install; npm run dev;   ?

Comment: didn't work. first i ran npm install and then npm run dev
It ran successfully but didn't resolve my issue

Comment: I could try opening dev tools (press F12) and see what the errors are.